# Xcode: Enable Create Git Repository after disabling it

Tags: ios, xcode, git, swift, github

Like the  Title already says:

I created a Xcode Project and i accidentally disabled : "Create Git Repository"

Does someone know, if i can enable it again ?
I don't want to delete this project and start from the beginning again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This button basically does `git init`.

So just call `git init` in your Terminal in the relevant project folder. Afterwards you can add remotes and do commits and pushes. Xcode will recognize the repository automatically.

Comment: I never pushed this project. I just want to enable "Create Git Repository"

Comment: Like I said, just call `git init`.

Comment: Thanks but if i try to push it now, xcode says: The current branch could not be determined. I also tried it with terminal. i did cd "MyFile" then: git remote add origin https://MYURL.com git push -u origin master
It also didn't work ... I get the following error:
error: src refspec master does not match any. error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'
btw: If i open my Xcode Project, in the left sidebar there are question marks next to my files...

Comment: You have to add a branch called `master` on your remote repository. The question marks only show that these aren't added to git yet.

Comment: How do i add a branch on my remote repository? Is it easy? Sorry I´m new to Git..

Comment: Mostly this is done by default, if you're on GitHub that may not be your issue. Have you added files (`git add somefile.txt`) committed (`git commit -m 'my commit message'`) before you tried to push?

Comment: I did it like this now: Koray$ echo "MyPr" >> README.md then this: git init then this: git add README.md then this: git commit -m "first commit" then this: git push -u origin master. Everything actually worked... It uploaded the ReadMe.md file... But my Project is still not on GitHub. Just the ReadMe.md file... Did i forgot something?

Comment: Jep, you also need to add your project related files (you only added the README). Do `git add -A` then `git commit -m 'files added'` then `git push`. That should do it.

Comment: I get following message: 
Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
I tried this:    git config --global user.name "MyUserName", but nothing happened...

Comment: Then try to set the email as well. You can check the settings via `git config -l`.

Comment: Okay i got following message: [master af2d9eb] files added
 17 files changed, 2455 insertions(+) but when i go my GitHub Project Url, nothing is there. Just the Readme.md.... Where did i uploaded my files :O ?

Comment: Yep. Im getting following message: BerlinSwift https://github.com/myprofile/myproject (fetch)
MyPr https://github.com/myprofile/myproject (fetch) (push)
origin https://github.com/myprofile/myproject (fetch) (fetch)
origin https://github.com/myprofile/myproject (fetch)t (push)